# How to Dynamically display an webview within an fragment based on selected value in spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

My app 2 spinners  ,which basically are drop down lists allowing users to select values. Spinner1 has 4options in dropdown and Spinner2 has 5options in dropdown.

If user selects option1 from spinner1 and option1 from spinner2 , a bulleted list [in the HTML webapp version of this app , i use li tags] should be displayed in a fragment in rest of the view.The image will make things more clear.
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhI7i.jpg
Now if i use a webview within a fragment to display the text ,how can i dynamically do that for the 20 conditions[ 4 options in spinner 1 and 4 options in spinner2 , so 4*5]?

I am attaching the code

```
package com.temp1.android;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    private Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    }

    //add items into spinner dynamically
    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Equipment");
        list.add("Indications");
        list.add("Illustration");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    //get the selected dropdown list value
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                        "OnClickListener : " + 
                        "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                        "\nSpinner 2 : " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });



    }

}





import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
                "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Presently i am using an toast for debugging event listeners

Comment: You do you want the `WebView` in a `Fragment`? I don't see what is difficult, just add the `Fragment` with the `WebView` to a container layout in the `R.layout.main` and implement a method in it ``updateWebView`(int firstSpinnerPosition, int secondSpinnerPosition)`. Using that method you can easily update the `WebView` from an array using those int values.

Comment: How can i provide the input to webview dynamically? Because i have 20 different strings to display depending on spinners[4items in 1st spinner * 5items in 2nd spinner].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you had the fragment part done, so I would assume you have a `Fragment` in your layout file `R.layout.main` with the id `R.id.webviewfrag`.

The class for that fragment could be like this:

```
public class WebViewerFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;
    // a two dimensional array representing the data to put in the WebView
    private String[][] mData = new String[4][5];// put data in it

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
        return mainView;
    }

    public void updateWebView(int firstSelection, int secondSelection) {
         if (firstSelection == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION || secondSelection == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
              return;  
         } else {
              if (mWebView != null) {
                   mWebView.loadData(mData[firstSelection][secondSelection], "text/html", null);
              }
         }
    }
}
```

`R.layout.frag_layout` would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then all you have to do in `onClick` callback is:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
       WebViewerFragment wvf = (WebViewerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.webviewfrag);
       if (wvf != null && wvf.getView() != null) { 
            wvf.updateWebView(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition(), spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
       }
}
```